# Centering a Label vertically in a horizontal layout

Tags: c++, css, qt, user-interface, padding

I am having a bit of a problem with centering my `QLabel` vertically within a `QHBoxLayout`. The relevant piece of my code is below:

```
QFrame* topBar = new QFrame();
topBar->setStyleSheet("background-color: #2c3d50;border-bottom: 3px solid #2c92b6;");
topBar->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
topBar->setFixedHeight(24);

QHBoxLayout* topBarLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    QLabel* label = new QLabel("MSFT");
    label->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
    label->setStyleSheet("font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;border: 0px;");
    label->setMinimumHeight(15);
    topBarLayout->addWidget(label);

topBar->setLayout(topBarLayout);
topLayout->addWidget(topBar);
```

My local goal is *to have the label vertically centered*. What I tried:

1. `Qt::AlignVCenter` - had no impact
2. `QSizePolicy::PreferredSize` and `QSizePolicy::Expanding` caused the label to be vertically shrunk without `minimumHeight`/`fixedHeight`, where I hoped it to expand freely to the height of the parent
3. Changing the `minimumHeight` or adding `padding/margin:`, which only continue to move the `QLabel` downwards.

[image: Described above]

My ultimate goal is to create a bar (that dark blue thing in the photo) of fixed height and variable width, with labels and buttons (e.g. caption, close, maximize etc.) aligned on the both sides, regardless of the bar's width.

Internets say that adding yet another `QBoxLayout` to center the `Label` vertically could solve the problem, but I will be adding lots of components to that bar, so this "solution" would be very impractical.

**TL;DR: How does one align a `Label` (or simply its text) vertically within a horizontal layout?**

Comment: @G.M. as my post states, using the alignment property wasn't of much help, with results shown in the picture.

Comment: @GCyrillus well this is Qt, HTML is not generated and stylesheets are present in the code excerpt above.

Comment: What happens if you simply remove the calls to `setSizePolicy`?

Comment: @G.M. The default policy (`Preferred/Preferred`) is used, which causes maximum stretch in the horizontal direction (default `Label` behavior, according to the sources) and behavior #2 in the vertical direction, as mentioned above.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [MCVE] that results in the image shown in your post.  Sorry, but without that I'm not sure I fully understand the issue.

Comment: @G.M. The example provided is a base that can be simply extended using the comments in the numbered list to achieve the results depicted. I do not deny that the layout mechanism is completely new to me, but I feel that I have provided a description and question of a clarity, which doesn't necessarily call for reminding one of the principles of turning up with a question the one has obviously complied with on numerous occasions. If not otherwise possible, a general answer shedding some light on a practice achieving result as described in the very last question would be of considerable help.

Comment: I always get the labels vertical-centered by default with a minimum example, even when using your stylesheet and size-policies, until I set the minimum-size on the labels then they are pushed to bottom (or even cropped). If I increase the height of the frame it works fine. If you put a background-color on the labels you see a sort of padding in the container. They are not aligned bottom but just too big to be centered in that height.

Comment: @ymoreau thank you, but given that the height of the frame can not be changed much (it would be too big for the design), in what ways could I make the `Label` smaller so that it appears to be centered properly? `minimumHeight`, `fixedHeight` ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change top/bottom margins of the layout and keep `Qt::AlignVCenter`:

```
topBarLayout->setContentsMargins(9,0,9,5);
```

Comment: From what I tested it is vertically centered by default, I did not need the `Qt::AlignVCenter`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. As @ymoreau mentioned, `Qt::AlignVCenter` wasn't necessary.